Sup-norm bound on the deviation of inverse sample covariance
Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$ be a Gaussian random matrix, i.e. $X_{ij}\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} N(0,1)$. Suppose $N>M$ and $X^{\top}X$ is invertible, then what can we say about
\begin{align*}
\left\|\left(\frac{X^{T}X}{N}\right)^{-1}-I\right\|_{\text{max}}\lesssim \ ?
\end{align*}
where $\|A\|_{\text{max}}:=\text{max}_{ij} |A_{ij}|$ is the entry-wise supremum norm.
It seems that the entry in the matrix $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ has heavy tail, could we get
\begin{align*}
\left\|\left(\frac{X^{T}X}{N}\right)^{-1}-I\right\|_{\text{max}}\lesssim \sqrt{ \frac{ \text{log} M}{N}}
\end{align*}
under some suitable assumptions on $M$ and $N$?
Appreciate any comments!
